# Passing Name from Parameter to Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

Can I do something like this :

```
public int CountSpesific(string queryString, string namaKategori, string namaLaporan)
{
    var results = GetSearchResults(queryString); //will result in list
    var count = results.Where(o => o.KlasifikasiLaporan == namaLaporan 
                                  && o.[namaKategori] == true).Count();

    return count;
}
```

I want `[namaKategori]` changed based on parameter

Comment: You will have to use reflection and find the property info. As long as it is Linq and Not EF, there should not be a problem.

Comment: If it is to be provided by a `string` containing name of the member, Harsh is correct. Other option is to use `Func<[TYPE_OF_o], bool>`, if it is only used from code and member is known beforehand

Comment: What is `o` in this lambda? Some type? Can you edit it? Then just add a method to it to retrieve value for specified property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get property info and then fetch the value. In below code `YourType` is the type of `o` in the lambda expression.

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null));

public int CountSpesific(string queryString, string namaKategori, string namaLaporan)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop = typeof(YourType).GetProperty(namaKategori);

    var results = GetSearchResults(queryString); //will result in list
    var count = results.Where(o => o.KlasifikasiLaporan == namaLaporan 
                           && (bool)prop.GetValue(o) == true).Count();

    return count;
}
```

Comment: i got this error `operator == cannot be applied to operand of type object and bool`